# Java quick test to see if a proxy is available

Tags: java, network-programming, network-protocols

I have a list of proxy servers, which I have to delete all those not available or does not respond within a preset timeout. I tried with:

```
isPinghed=InetAddress.getByName("46.183.162.4").isReachable(10000);
```

but isPinghed is always false and I also realized that this solution is dependent on the OS. Someone might suggest another solution, to test starting from the IP and port if the proxy is available in java?

Comment: Try connecting to it with TCP.  The server might not respond to anything else.

Comment: The way to detect whether *any* resource is available is to try to use it.